# Expect four printouts from while loop, getting only one

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm trying to write a program using a while loop that gives an output based on range of input variable declared.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
  
int main() {
    
    float fahren = 0;
    float celsius;
  
    while (fahren < 400) {
        // convert fahreneheit to celsius 
        // Subtract 32, then multiply it by 5, then divide by 9
         
        celsius = 5 * (fahren - 32) / 9;
        cout << celsius;
        fahren+= 100;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect 4 values to be returned, however I only get 1, which is the value at 0.

Comment: don't confuse "return" and "print on the screen". Those are different things and mixing them up causes confusion. Coincidentally, your code really does return only a single number and that is `0`

Comment: @pm100 Why does the code in your link have `<< "\n"`? The OP's code doesn't have that.

Comment: @JohnKugelman simply so that I can see each output value separatly to be sure I got 4. The output looks the same without it, just all on one line

Comment: @pm100: But I think it is the OP's confusion actually.

Comment: @Jarod42 op says he gets 0 as output

Comment: @pm100 Actually, OP says "... value *at* 0". Voting to close as Not Reproducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You print 4 values but without separator, you might add `std::cout << std::endl;`

```
while (fahren < 400) {
    // convert fahreneheit to celsius 
    // Subtract 32, then multiply it by 5, then divide by 9
     
    celsius = 5 * (fahren - 32) / 9;
    std::cout << celsius << std::endl; // added new line here
    fahren += 100;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fae8e0c6ab9a20ed)